# Error datatable with laravel and mysql :DataTables warning: table id=example - ajax error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datatable

I'm using datatable in my laravel application. When I have one record everything is well and the data is displayed in the data table but when I have more then two records for example I get this error :

```
DataTables warning: table id=example - ajax error
```

Some times its works well but when I refresh the page I get the same error, this is my script:

```
   <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{{ URL::route('ADMIN-AJAX-USERS') }}',
            columns: [
                { data: 'companyName', name: 'companyName' },
                { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
                { data: 'companyNum', name: 'companyNum' },
                { data: 'statut', name: 'statut' },
                { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
                { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

UPDATE:

the server  respond with this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: I think its a typo,
for the jquery selector `$('#example')` you've added a trailing space character which looks like `$('#example ')`

Comment: There's more to that error than what you're showing. There's also a number and a link to the documentation. Let's see that. Also, let's see the server side code.

Comment: the server respond with Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed   ajax: '{{ URL::route('ADMIN-AJAX-USERS') }}',
maybe I am mistaken but I think you can't use both url and route.You have to choose one.

Comment: the problem wasn't that , I tried to rewrite my code and it worked. and effectively there is no need to use "route", thank you for your reply, +1 vote